# Cannot compile Bootstrap 3 LESS main file (bootstrap.less) using Grunt?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, gruntjs

I'm not able to compile the "main" `bootstrap.less` into `'<%= pkg.name %>.css'`. I'm getting this error running `grunt less`:

```
Running "less:dist" (less) task
>> ParseError: Syntax Error on line 643 in bower_components\bootstrap\less\mixins.less:643:25
>> padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
>> &:extend(.clearfix all);
>> }
Warning: Error compiling LESS. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

My configuration for `less` task is fairly simple:

```js
less: {
    options: {
        strictMath: true
    },
    dist: {
        files: {
            'dist/assets/css/<%= pkg.name %>.css': [
                '<%= bootstrap_less %>/bootstrap.less',
                'src/assets/less/style.less'
            ]
        }
    }
},

// Arbitrary properties used in task configuration templates.
bower_components: 'bower_components',
bootstrap_less: '<%= bower_components %>/bootstrap/less'
```

Error line in `mixins.less` (not modified by me in any way):

```css
// Centered container element
.container-fixed() {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left:  (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
  padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
  &:extend(.clearfix all);
}
```

Please also not I'm new to Grunt and maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: run grunt with `--verbose` and see what it says. did you update any (bower) package lately? could be a breaking change with one of less' dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your version of `less` is outdated? `:extend()` is a new-ish feature of Less.

Comment: I've replaced grunt-contrib (the whole package) with grunt-contrib-less alone and not it's working. Thanks!